# Hibernate inheritance from class from another project

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, annotations

I am wrapping the following class from another project. It should not be annotated with Hibernate annotations:

```
public class Response
{
    private String access;

    ...

    public String getAccess()
    {
        return this.access;
    }

    public void setAccess(String access)
    {
        this.access = access;
    }

    ...
}
```

This is the "wrapper-class" (for persistence) in my current project.
However the properties from the `Response` superclass aren't mapped. (eg. `Access`)
(Only the added property `entry_id` is mapped.)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ruleEngineResponse")
public class RuleEngineResponse extends Response
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "entry_id")
    private Long entry_id = -1L;

    public void setId(Long entry_id)
    {
        this.entry_id = entry_id;
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return this.entry_id;
    }

    // Problem: this property is not mapped
    @Column(name = "access")
    @Override
    public String getAccess()
    {
        return super.getAccess();
    }

    ...
}
```

How could i configure the `RuleEngineResponse` to map the properties form the `Response` superclass without touching the Response superclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, because some of the annotations are placed to fields and other annotations are placed to attributes. In JPA 2.0 specification this is told with following words:

> All such classes in the entity hierarchy whose access type is
>   defaulted in this way must be consistent in their placement of
>   annotations on either fields or properties, such that a single,
>   consistent default access type applies within the hierarchy.

What happens in case of Hibernate is that access type ends up to *field*, because  `@Id` annotation is placed to field. As consequence annotations in `getAccess` and other in methods as well are ignored.

If you want to keep current class hierarchy and do not want to define variable `access` again in RuleEngineResponse, annotations should be places to methods:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ruleEngineResponse")
public class RuleEngineResponse extends Response {

    private Long entry_id = -1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "entry_id")
    public Long getId() {
        return this.entry_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "access")
    @Override
    public String getAccess() {
        return super.getAccess();
    }
    ...
}
```

If because of some reason mixing property and field access is preferred, that can be done with [@AccessType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AccessType.html) annotation. You can also consider using [MappedSuperClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) as suggested in other answers, but also then conflicts in annotation placement have to be solved.

Comment: thanks that solved my problem. i moved the definitions to the method (and i did not use the mappedsuperclass tag.)

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution to this problem is to annotate `Response` with `@MappedSuperclass`. If you cannot do it, you should be able to declare the same thing in `orm.xml` as follows:

```
<mapped-superclass class = "Response" />
```

See [Chapter 3. Overriding metadata through XML](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html).